# Tools to create a digital status board

Tags: drag-and-drop, digital, kanban

In my company we are using a board to present status of the tickets. Something like kanban board but with more columns. So a chit is a ticket that you put on the table, that is drawn on the board. Columns (sometimes split into rows rows) represent status  (development, in testing, etc.). Problem is that this is all manual. I am looking for software to help me setup digital one. I would need:

- possibility to integrate with jira (board <-> jira)
- fully customizable (look of sinlgle ticket, table setup)
- drag and drop option
- possible free

I am not afraid to write it from scratch (in java) but if there is something that can help me I am open to suggestions.

Regards

Comment: This question is off-topic because it's not within the scope for this site, as defined in [What topics can I ask about here?](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Also see: [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](//stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) You may be able to ask on [another Stack Exchange site](//stackexchange.com/sites#name), for example [pm.se] or [softwareengineering.se]. Be sure to read the on-topic page in the help center for any site on which you intend to post a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try [SwiftKanban](http://www.digite.com/swiftkanban) - it integrates with JIRA and has all of the capabilities you are looking for.  There is a free version - but for the JIRA integration option, you do need to pay for it.

Your other option might be to try Trello - which is now acquired by Atlassian, the maker of JIRA - and may be integrated with it.

Disclaimer: I work for the company that has developed SwiftKanban.

Answer (score -1):

There are many tools you can pick up from. 
As being part of Kanbanzie, I can definitely suggest it. It is integrated with JIRA, drag and drop function is available and you have 30-day free trial. You can also use a [portfolio Kanban approach](https://kanbanize.com/kanban-resources/portfolio-kanban/) in order to manage multiple project.

I think Workfront and Asana are good options as well.

Good luck.

Comment: Pavel, it will be fair to note that you are affiliated with Kanbanize ;)